# How to add additional peers to the WebRTC session with already two existing peers

Tags: webrtc, p2p, peer

I have used WebRTC to make p2p audio and video connection.
With only two peers I get the order of invocation.

**Peer1-caller** sends SDP offer and ICE candidates.
**Peer2-callee** receives SDP offer and ICE candidates generates SDP answer and it's ICE candidates send it back to the caller which adds them.

Now let's say I want **Peer3** to join the session with two existing peers.
What would be the process?

1. - **Peer3** sends SDP offer and ICE candidates to both previous peers and both **Peer1-caller** and **Peer2-callee** send back SDP answers, I suppose I would have to have ICE candidates from previous peers stored somewhere?
2. - **Peer3** has to wait for SDP offers from **Peer1-caller** and **Peer2-callee** and send back SDP answer to both of them?
3. - Initiator **Peer1-caller** sends SDP offer to **Peer3** which responds with SDP answer and after ICE candidates are exchanged between all three peers they can all see each other?
4. - Something else?

Basically I am confused how to add **third peer**, which method to use `peerConnection.createOffer()` than wait for SDP answers from all other peers including the initiator or wait for SDP offer(s) and use `peerConnection.createAnswer()`?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RTC*Peer*Connection is just that, a connection talking to a single endpoint. If you want to more than one, you'll need a separate peerconnection for each, complete with its own independent offer-answer exchange.

https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/multiple/ is a minimal demo.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't knew that. Example from your link uses 4 peerConection objects for 3 peers. As I have understood, for example if we have three peers A, B and C than in code implementation it would be enough to have 2 peerConnection objects? To represent it like this A ->(B, C), B->(C, A), C->(A, B), number of peerConnection objects needed for each client that loads the script is number of members in parenthesis. Can it be done like that also, with two peerConnection objects for 3 peers?

Comment: that example is all-local. If you are peer A and have peers B and C you will need one RTCPeerConnection for each. It is usuable in both directions (even though you could use two one-way connections)

Comment: So in that example two one-way connections are used for Peer1 and two one-way connections for Peer2 which makes it four RTCPeerConnection objects? Just to make it clear, it could also be done using two RTCPeerConnection objects for two other peers B and C, each RTCPeerConnection object used in both directions?